# How to get the String Value in JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, get

This is my JSON

```
{
    "StatusResponse": 
    {
        "StatusCode": "000"
        "StatusDescription": "Operation Success(000)"
        "DebugDescription": "OperationSuccess"
    }-
    "memId": "3e369fec-a9c5-418b-a950-0647f7e15d7c"
    "token": null
    "isAdmin": false
    "isTeacher": false
    "isParent": true
    "kinderId": null
}
```

I can retrieve the dictionary of `StatusResponse` by using the Http Get method.

```
RestApiManager.sharedInstance.makeGetRequest("myURL", onCompletion: {json in
        for result in json["StatusResponse"].dictionaryValue
        {
            print(result)
        }
    })
```

At here, my result output will be like this.

```
("DebugDescription", OperationSuccess)
("StatusDescription", Operation Success(000))
("StatusCode", 000)
```

The question I want to ask is how to get the stringValue of StatusCode in my code there by using FOR EACH loop?

Comment: OP, you're using SwiftyJSON, it would be a good thing to mention it in your question...

Comment: json["StatusResponse"]["StatusCode"]?

Comment: My answer works for you.Tick and up vote my answer.It is helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
if let statusCode = json["StatusResponse"]["StatusCode"].string {
    println(statusCode)
}
```

Comment: @Ramest_T what if I want to use for each loop?

Comment: It will print complete dictionary. If you want a particular value from your response. use yourResponseDict["requiredKey"].

Answer (score 0):

```
   let statusCodeValue = json["StatusResponse"]["StatusCode"].stringValue
   print("The ststusCodeValue is - \(stausCodeValue)")

   let tatusDescriptionValue = json["StatusResponse"]["StatusDescription"].stringValue
   print("The statusDescriptionValue is - \(statusDescriptionValue)")

   let debugDescriptionValue = json["StatusResponse"]["DebugDescription"].stringValue
   print("The debugDescriptionValue is - \(DebugDescriptionValue)")
```

Comment: I also do like this before, but it's not working unfortunately...Error is here => Type '(String, JSON)' has no subscript members

Comment: Type '(String, JSON)' has no subscript members...this is the error that shown by Xcode